# How to write some data to .xml file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

Right now I have to build a website for school which is an online shop, and right now I'm doing the shop part which I need to have something like a txt file or xml to have the data like, name, price, img, description something like that.  Right now it is reading a xml file and creating the items on them shop based on that file, but now i need to implement a function like "add a new product to the store" but I can't seem to append data to that xml file and I dont know why, I've tried php but it really doesn't work. Here's some of my html code:

This is the form for adding the item:

```
<form action="Adicionar_produto.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="image"/>
    <input type="text" name="price"> 
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="add"/>
</form>
```

And this is the php script I tried but that its currently no used:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['OK'])){
    $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
    $xml -> load("Produtos.xml");
    $rootTag = $xml -> getElementsByTagName("CATALOG")->item(0); 
    $dataTag = $xml->createElement("item");
    $nameTag = $xml->createElement("name",$_REQUESTE['name']);
    $imageTag = $xml->createElement("image",$_REQUESTE['image']);
    $priceTag = $xml->createElement("price",$_REQUESTE['price']);
    $dataTag->appendChild($nameTag);
    $dataTag->appendChild($imageTag);
    $dataTag->appendChild($priceTag);
    $rootTag->appendChild($dataTag);
    $xml->save("Produtos.xml");
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there no online shop framework that already includes all features you need? It seems wasteful to do it from scratch.

Comment: cna you give the url to the that framework pls, so that i can check it out

Comment: You can search for open-source e-commerce platforms, there are lots of them.

Answer (score 0):

If the exercise is to practice your raw php, then maybe try [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). Here is an example of it's use. Also, you are looking for `$_REQUEST['OK']` but your form says `$_REQUEST['ok']` (lowercase `ok`):

```
if(!empty($_POST['ok'])) {
    $Xml    =   simplexml_load_file("Produtos.xml");
    $Item   =   $Xml->CATALOG->addChild('item');
    $Item->addChild('name',$_POST['name']));
    $Item->addChild('image',$_POST['image']);
    $Item->addChild('price',$_POST['price']);
    $Xml->asXml("Produtos.xml");
}
```

More or less gives you *(I don't know what your base array is named, I just named it `config`)*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <CATALOG>
        <item>
            <name>test</name>
            <image>brd</image>
            <price>123123</price>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>goood</name>
            <image>masss</image>
            <price>3212321</price>
        </item>
    </CATALOG>
</config>
```

Comment: Another problem is, how do i add a php script to my html file, do i need to alter the file type to .php, cus a simple 
           <php ?> 
or a
            <scrip language="php"> </script> 
doesnt seems to work

Comment: What do you mean add a php script to you html?

Comment: i very new at this web thing, to implement php to an .html paga what do i have to insert,

           <php 
           ?>

something like this right ?

Comment: You have to use `.php` and the tags you mentioned in order to run php scripts.